# how to check if modal panel is opened using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, richfaces

Don't know how to check if modal Panel has been opened or not.

```
<a4j:commandButton id="backButtonId" value="#{msg.back}"
      action="#{someCommonAction}"
      oncomplete="if (  MyModalPanel Has Been Opened) #{rich:component('MyModalPanel').hide() else Nothing;"
                           />
```

How can i do it with **javascript** but not using managed beans?

thank you for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`jQuery.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) for this wherein you check if the element is [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).

```
oncomplete="if (#{rich:component('MyModalPanel')}.is(':visible')) #{rich:component('MyModalPanel')}.hide();"
```

But this is useless. It doesn't harm to call `hide()` on an already hidden modal panel.

```
oncomplete="#{rich:component('MyModalPanel')}.hide();"
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should do the trick for you:

```
#{rich:component('MyModalPanel')}.shown
```